# Create .Zip file of Images

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposer

I'm wondering how I can create a .zip file with images in it. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by calling `addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:` on the `MFMailComposeViewController` - if you already have the zip file.

If your question includes creating the zip file, unfortunately that is not possible with a few method calls in iOS. You would need to use a third-party library for this, e. g. [objective-zip](https://github.com/flyingdolphinstudio/Objective-Zip).

Comment: Thank you for noticing! Apparently they moved it to github, I've changed the link accordingly.

Comment: Thanks... I found this link yesterday and its working smoothly +1 though for you... :)

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible go here to find out:

[Class Refrence](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

look for the add atachment method.

Comment: I know how to attach it, I want to know how to make a .zip file filled with images.